# "Next" button does not cycle through answers as expected

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a very basic, pure JavaScript app (no jQuery).

Using jQuery I feel like I'd be able to do this easily. But JavaScript not so much.

Here is my JSF app:

http://jsfiddle.net/abustamam/CLenJ/2/

So the purpose is for the question and its accompanying answers to be cycled through when the "Next" button is pressed.

Problem is, nothing happens when "next" is pressed. Even if I set the `next()` function to be something like

```
function next() {
    alert("pressed!");
}
```

nothing happens.

At the suggestion of another question, I changed the "onLoad" into No wrap - in head.

At this point, the question and values are not initially loaded.

On looking at the console errors, it seems like the load order plays a big difference on whether or not the button works, or whether or not the first question will load, but I can't find a way to get them both work concurrently.

Can someone shed some light? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the fiddle, your script was under the `load` callback which means the `next` method is inside a closure so it is not available in the global scope.

If you look at the browser console you could see a script error saying `Uncaught ReferenceError: next is not defined`

In the left hand side panel in the second dropdown under `Frameworks and Extensions` select `No Wrap - In Body`

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5wpuQ/)

Comment: Wow thanks. Now I have to figure out why the score counter isn't working correctly, but I'll try to do that on my own. Thanks again!